# Глюк во втором списке при выборе первого

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

При выборе первого поля, меняется значения второго. Но при первом открытии страницы, во втором поле, должно быть по умолчанию только "Выберите модель", а у меня выводятся все значения. После того, как выбираю второй или третий все поправляется. В чем глюк? Даже selected добавил, не помогает.

```
<select name="first" id="first">
        <option value="one" selected>Выберите марку</option>
        <option value="two">BMW</option>
        <option value="tri">Audi</option>
             </select>
    <select name="second" id="second">
        <option value="one" class="one" selected>Выберите модель</option>
        <option value="two" class="two">Второй 1</option>
        <option value="two" class="two">Второй 2</option>
        <option value="two" class="two">Второй 3</option>
        <option value="tri" class="tri">третий</option>
        <option value="tri" class="tri">третий 2</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    $('#first').change(function(){
        var cls = $(this).val();
        $('#second option').hide();
        $('#second ' + '.' + cls).show();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Не думаю что глюк, у вас же `hide` происходит только после изменения первого селекта.

Comment: `<style>.two { display: none; } .tri { display: none; }</style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно, чтобы `option` из второго `select` не отображались при загрузке страницы. Для этого есть несколько способов.

***С помощью CSS***

Не отображаем все опции, кроме выбранной

```
#second option:not([selected]) {
  display: none;
}
```

***С помощью HTML***

Добавляем каждой `option` атрибут `style="display: none"`

```
<select name="second" id="second">
    <option value="one" class="one" selected>Выберите модель</option>
    <option value="two" class="two" style="display: none">Второй 1</option>
    <option value="two" class="two" style="display: none">Второй 2</option>
    <option value="two" class="two" style="display: none">Второй 3</option>
    <option value="tri" class="tri" style="display: none">третий</option>
    <option value="tri" class="tri" style="display: none">третий 2</option>
</select>
```

***С помощью jQuery***

Скрыть `option` по готовности объектной модели документа

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#second option:not([selected])').hide();
});
```